# How to wrap text inside bootstrap button without changing button size?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to wrap or resize text inside bootstrap button without changing button size.I have couple buttons that must be aligned

I've used this class,text is wrap but button grows in size affecting the alignment with other buttons

```
 .btn-wrap-text {
    white-space: normal !important;
    word-wrap: break-word !important;
}
```

There is sample code,just resize the view:
https://jsfiddle.net/mrapi/3yv314dx/1/

thanks

Comment: you can change the font size for the different viewport.

Comment: you can use a hover tooltip and simplify the button text

Comment: @Sami: can you gave me a sample code.thanks

Comment: I am asking you to use media query like @media (max-width: 1024px) {.btn-wrap-text {font-size: 12px;}} . (this will work for tablet)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/3yv314dx/3/

```js
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```

```css
.btn-outline {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: inherit;
    transition: all .5s;
}

.btn-wrap-text {
    overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
             <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block btn-outline">
                        ARTICLE                        
                    </button>
                </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block btn-outline">
                       ARTICLE                  
                    </button>
                </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block btn-outline">
                         ARTICLE WITH LONGER NAME
                    </button>
                </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block btn-outline">
                         ARTICLE       
                    </button>
                </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block btn-outline">
                        ARTICLE               
                    </button>
                </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block btn-outline">
                       ARTICLE             
                    </button>
                </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block btn-outline">
                        ARTICLE WITH LONGER NAME
                    </button>
                </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4"> 
                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block btn-outline btn-wrap-text" data-toggle="tooltip" title="ARTICLE WITH LONGER NAME">
                       ARTICLE WITH LONGER NAME
                    </button>
                </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block btn-outline">
                        ARTICLE                        
                    </button>
                </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block btn-outline">
                        ARTICLE                         
                    </button>
                </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block btn-outline">
                        ARTICLE                        
                    </button>
                </div>
               <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block btn-outline">
                        ARTICLE                        
                    </button>
                </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block btn-outline">
                        ARTICLE                        
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
   
   
           </div>  
  </div>
```

Here in the solution, I've used ellipse to truncate extra characters & to show entire text used `tooltip`

Comment: longer text still goes out from button,resize the view.thanks

Comment: That's because I haven't added class to other buttons. I added to only one button..

Comment: Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/3yv314dx/4/ .. You need to add `btn-wrap-text` class to all the buttons.

Comment: I's a solution.thanks,but I want to see the text. Isn't possible to wrap it without affecting the button?

Comment: @mrapi... Without truncating or without effecting the button size it's not possible.

Answer (score 13):

Not sure why all the complicated solutions.

Just add the following to your `.btn` css:

```
white-space: normal;
```

So, if you already have a `.btn` in your global css file, do this:

```css
.btn {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Or if you do not have anything in your global css file, just do it inline, such as:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="white-space: normal;">This is some button with text that should wrap</button>
```

> **Note:** This method may not work on archaic versions of IE

Comment: it changes the height

Comment: @MacGyver - Text wrapping is going to cause a the button height to change (if you have a fixed width button). Good option to try to prevent that is to use `@media` font size reduction in combination with this method.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 3):

You can change the font size. If you dont want to change the font size use the below code

```
.btn-wrap-text {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```